# PHP - Load only current post with _GET

Tags: php, get, load, dropdown

Im new on PHP and Im making a list with posts, and I want to make a dropdown who loads with `$_GET` method, full post.
Now, when I press on *View* its opens all posts, but I need only one, current who I press.
There's my code

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET["deleteNews"])){
            $newsID = $_GET["id"];
            deleteNews($connection, $newsID);
            unset($_GET["deleteNews"]);
        }

        $listQuery = "SELECT * FROM `news` GROUP BY date_added DESC";
        $result = $connection->query($listQuery);
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $tr_ID = $row->id;
    ?>
    <div class="list-item">
        <div class="list-content">
            <div class="column added"><? echo date("d.m.Y",$row->date_added) ?> (<?php echo $row->author; ?>)</div>
            <div class="column title"><?php echo $row->title; ?></div>
            <div class="column start-text"><? echo shorten($row->text, $length = 100); ?></div>
            <div class="column options">
                <a href="?readNews">View</a><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
            if(isset($_GET["readNews"])){
        ?>
        <div class="list-wrapper">
            <div class="list-news">
                <div class="head-content">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="/uploads/<?php echo $row->seo; ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <span><?php echo $row->text; ?></span>
                    <button class="sec-button" type="submit" onclick="refreshPage('/admin/pageNews')">Aizvērt</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?  }   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the id of the news item you're trying to view, the easiest way would be by modifying the view link:

```
<a href="?readNews=<?= $tr_ID ?>">View</a><br/>
```

Once this is done `$_GET['readNews']` will have the id of the selected item, you can then use this to determine whether to show the article or not:

```
if(isset($_GET["readNews"]) && $_GET['readNews'] == $tr_ID){
```

This will only display the body of the selected id.